# Laravel - Getting user from specific authentication guard

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication

I wanna create an API for my web application. In this API, a user is identified by a token. All works, but in my controller, when I wanna get user I must write something like this:

```
Auth::guard('api')->user();
```

Every time I must use this method to get user. I wanna use something like `$request->user()`, but this option return me `null` :(

What should I do if I wanna get from request user? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to also pass the guard to [`Request::user()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L882) method.

```php
$user = $request->user('api');
```

Or you can set the default guard for your API route group:

```php
Route::group(['domain' => 'api.app.dev', 'guard' => 'api'], function () {
    // ...
});
```

This way, you only need to set it once, and every time you call something like `Auth::user()`, you get the user object based on the previously set guard.

Have a look at this article for more on the topic:
[Setting the Guard Per Route in Laravel](http://mattallan.org/2016/setting-the-guard-per-route-in-laravel/)

Comment: Thanks for answer! :) I have one more question: when create api the best option is to create something like ApiController and there put all methods for api or for example for user method put method in UserController (which also have method for web application)?

Comment: I'd go with a separate `ApiController` to keep things a little bit cleaner.